# NSPanel loses focus although being modal

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, nspanel

I have a strange problem with one of my NSPanels. Starting up my application, I use a simple panel with only an NSTextField and an NSButton to get the player's name. Working on some other stuff on my application, all of a sudden the panel does not get focused any longer when starting the app. The button does work, though, but the text field refuses to be focused and take any input.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Cheers,

Living

Comment: Correct. But it might be of interest, though. Do you want me to reword it to be a question that I do answer myself?

Comment: Yes. [It's OK to ask and answer your own questions.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Rob, thank's for pointing out, I was not aware of that. Will be updating he thread asap.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself, shame on me.

For the NSPanel, I had deselected "Title Bar" in the Appearance section of the Attribute Inspector. Unchecked, the panel does not have a title bar and thus cannot get the focus.

Checking it again, everything works as expected :-)